# How to add an object to each array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, underscore.js

i have array of objects like this

```
var data=[{test:"a1"},{test:"b1"}];
```

need to add the one more object inside the object output should be like this

```
[  
   {  
      "test":"a1",
      "system":{  
         "tenentid":"xxxxx",
         "createdByUser":{  
            "lastName":"x",
            "firstName":"ABC"
         },
         "isdeleted":true
      }
   },
   {  
      "test":"b1",
      "system":{  
         "tenentid":"xxxxx",
         "createdByUser":{  
            "lastName":"x",
            "firstName":"ABC"
         },
         "isdeleted":true
      }
   }
]
```

plese can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate the array, add the property:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i].system = {}; //your new object here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it like we're writing node.js shall we?

```
data.forEach(function(someData){
    someData.system={};
});
```

Answer (score -2):

An easier way of doing it is:

```
for(var d of data) {
   d.system = {}; // Insert object here
}
```